# volatile and non-volatile bitfields

Tags: c, arm, volatile, bit-fields

I'm writing a code for Cortex-M0 CPU and gcc. I've the following structure:

```
struct {
    volatile unsigned flag1: 1;
    unsigned flag2: 1;

    unsigned foo; // something else accessed in main loop
} flags;
```

`flag1` is read and written from both GPIO interrupt handler and main loop. `flag2` is only read and written in main loop.

The ISR looks like this:

```
void handleIRQ(void) {
    if (!flags.flag1) {
        flags.flag1 = 1;
        // enable some hw timer
    }
}
```

The main loop looks like this:

```
for (;;) {
    // disable IRQ
    if (flags.flag1) {
        // handle IRQ
        flags.flag1 = 0;
        // access (rw) flag2 many times
    }
    // wait for interrupt, enable IRQ
}
```

When accessing `flag2` in main loop, will the compilier optimize access to it so it won't be fetched or stored to memory every time it is read or written to in code?

It's not clear to me because to set `flag1` in ISR, it will need to load whole `char`, set a bit and store it back.

Comment: What is `sizeof(struct flags)`?

Comment: I've updated the answer. There's an int after bit-fields. So the size should be 8.

Comment: You most probably don't want to use bit-fields for this. They are a minefield of implementation defined behaviour. Even if this was defined in the somewhere, I would not trust compiler to do the right thing.

Comment: @user694733 - That's an odd position. If it's defined by the standard, then why trust compilers on implementing anything else the standard says? If it's implementation defined, why use an implementation if you don't trust its documentation?

Comment: @StoryTeller Poor wording on my part. Should probably left the last sentence out. I meant; Even if it were defined by the *compiler vendor* (not C standard) and mentioned in the compiler manual, it could be changed in the next major compiler update, and could easily go unnoticed during update process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The volatile flag for just one bit isn't all that meaningful - it is possibly even harmful. What the compiler might do in practice is to allocate two chunks of memory, possibly each 32 bits wide. Because the volatile flag blocks it from combining the two bits inside the same allocated area, since there is no bit-level access instruction available.

> When accessing flag2 in main loop, will the compilier optimize access to it so it won't be fetched or stored to memory every time it is read or written to in code?

That's hard to tell, depends on how many data registers there are available. Disassemble the code and see.

Overall, bit-fields are not recommended since they are so poorly defined by the standard. And in this case, the individual volatile bit might lead to extra memory getting allocated.

Instead, you should do this:

```
volatile bool flag1;
bool flag2;
```

Assuming those flags aren't part of a hardware register, in which case the code was incorrect from the start and they should both be volatile.

Comment: It is my reading that volatile doesn't block them going into the same memory location. And indeed it seems that my GCC compiles them both into one `int` (sizeof a 2-bit struct is 4)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's very broken then. A read/write of `flag2` should not result in a read/write of the memory where `flag1` is located. It might not be the compiler's responsibility to handle this, but it clearly needs to be fixed. By for example replacing the bit-field with two booleans as in my example.

Comment: no, volatile doesn't forbid extra reads to it as it is a single memory location - to force it to be in a separate memory location, a zero-width member needs to be added in between

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Volatile doesn't forbid it, but it could break the code.

Comment: perhaps you're confusing atomic with volatile :)

Comment: I think what @Lundin means is that unintended read from volatile field could result in uninteded hardware operation. In my case, the `flag1` is just memory location but because it is volatile compiler should expect that it may be e.g. a bit in hardware register and reading it may cause side effects.

Answer (score 11):

It is my reading of the C11 standard that it is not proper to use a bitfield for this - even if both of them were declared as `volatile`. The following excerpt is from [3.14 Memory location](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.14):

> 1. **Memory location**
>      Either an object of scalar type, or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width
> 2. **NOTE 1** Two threads of execution can update and access **separate memory locations** without interfering with each other.
> 3. **NOTE 2** **It is not safe to concurrently update two non-atomic bit-fields in the same structure if all
>      members declared between them are also (non-zero-length) bit-fields**, no matter what the sizes of those
>      intervening bit-fields happen to be.

There is no exception given for `volatile`. Thus it wouldn't be safe to use the above bitfield if both threads of execution (i.e. the main and the ISR) if ISR will update one flag and the main will update another. The solution given is to add a member of size 0 in between to force them be placed in different memory locations. But then again, it would mean that both flags would consume at least one byte of memory, so it is again just simpler to use  a non-bit-field `unsigned char` or `bool` for them:

```
struct {
    volatile bool flag1;
    bool flag2;

    unsigned foo; // something else accessed in main loop
} flags;
```

Now they will be placed in different memory locations and they can be updated without them interfering with each other.

---

However the `volatile` for `flag1` is still strictly necessary because otherwise updates to `flag1` would be *side-effect free* in the main thread, and the compiler could deduce that it can keep that field in a register only - or that nothing need to be updated at all.

However, one needs to note that under **C11**, even the guarantees of `volatile` might not be enough: [5.1.2.3p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p5):

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits, as does the state of the floating-point environment if it is modified by the handler and not restored to its original state.

Thus, if full compatibility is required, `flag1` ought to be for example of type `volatile _Atomic bool`; it might even be possible to use an `_Atomic` bitfield. Both of these require a C11 compiler, however.

Then again, you can check the manuals of your compiler if they guarantee that an access to such volatile objects is also guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: Where did you find this text in the standard?

Comment: Thought so. Notes are not normative text in ISO standards! But of course the note is correct, this is some weird code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Notes, foot notes and examples are not normative. Also, using `unsigned char` for bit fields is not specified by C. The language only allows `_Bool` and (signed/unsigned) `int`. So there is no telling what the "fix" will do, if the compiler will at all accept it.